# Meaning of word егоза

Tags: перевод

I was reading the following blog https://ru-abandoned.livejournal.com/1501621.html and couldn't find a translation of the word "ягоза" that made sense from the context. According to the dictionary, "ягоза" is a "fidgety person". A quick search on google brings up a video clip entitled "ягоза- масленица"; and after watching this, it seems that this word can have also a somewhat more positive connotation, as in "can't stand still (from having so much fun)". The full sentence is "Свежий забор, **ягоза** и попискивающее дачло явно намекало на то, что незваным гостям там не рады". My translation is, "A new fence (COMMENT: I was also thinking that this could possibly mean 'live fence', as in being an 'electric fence') X and a beeping sensor clearly insinuates that uninvited guests are not welcome (here)"

Comment: In context of the blog post "ягоза" means a (specific kind of?) barbwire (you can see at the photos there).

Comment: Russian military and law enforcement are quite creative with the names for weapons, special equipment and such. There is a brand of handcuffs named *Нежность* ("tenderness"), a brand of police batons named *Аргумент* ("argument, reasoning") etc.

Comment: i would call it ***cynical*** rather than ***creative***, which is in agreement with Russian-style system of law enforcement (my apology for the use of this term)... **свежий забор** can't mean electric, rather newly built

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Егоза* is a brand of coiled barbed tape used by the Russian military.

Its original meaning is "fidgety person" indeed.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of the phrase дачло means датчик (motion sensor) and "Егоза" is a brand name of barbed tape.